# Qt - QDialog as a child does not have title bar

Tags: qt, qdialog

I notice that when using my `QDialog` as a child of my current `QMainWindow` ,
the title bar of the QDialog does not get displayed. However if the `QDialog` does not have a parent attached then title bar gets displayed. Any suggestions on how I can make the title bar appear when the `QDialog` is a child of my current form.I am on a Mac.

```
Mydialog.setParent(this); //The title bar will not show if a parent is set
if(Mydialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
 {
    ....     
  }
```

How can I make the title bar of my Qdialog show with a parent attached to it.

Comment: why don't you use `MyDialog dialog(this);`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mike said, you are supposed to construct the dialog object with the parent passed to the constructor instead of using `QObject::setParent()`, as many widget properties depend on the parent and it's properties and aren't changed when calling `setParent()`. Please try if this solves your title bar problem, too.